# webapi: set message in global exception handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

in my webapi project I have a global exception handler and I want to set the status code 500 when an exception is uncaught and I want to set a custom message, but I don't know how to set that message. Here is my code:

```
public class MyExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, context.Request);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

and the config is:

```
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.LocalOnly;

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());
```

In postman the response body is empty and I just see the 500 error code. So how to set a message here?

Comment: This will hep you to configure customer error message http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1133/aspnet-web-api-throw-custom-exception-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private TelemetryClient TelemetryClient { get; }

    public ExceptionFilter(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        TelemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new
        {
            error = context.Exception.Message
        });

        TelemetryClient.TrackException(context.Exception);
    }
}
```

and you can use it in your startup - ConfigureService:

```
services.AddSingleton<ExceptionFilter>();
services.AddMvc(
                options => { options.Filters.Add(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ExceptionFilter>()); });
```

it will now also send exception to azure telemetry.

You can offcourse remove the telemetryclient and the methods :)

cheers!

Comment: with this solution, if I have 10 controllers, each controller with it's own exception type, I need to add 10 filters... so this is not possible using the exception handler class?

Comment: @BudaGavril, why would you need that? the `context.Exception` contains the exception that each controller could throw..

Comment: see my comment above... so that when I add a new controller and exception type, this exception is handled by my exception handler without adding a new filter or editing an existing filter

Comment: perhaps I missing your point, but with this solution you don't need to add a  new filter each time you add a new controller...  could you perhaps clearify?

Comment: if I would add a new controller, I would add a new exception type for the mew controller and if I have a new exception type, I would need a new filter, unless I have a base exception, a filter for that exception and I derive a new exception for each controller...

Comment: but wait, why do you think you need a new filter? If you 'just' throw your exception, this will be catched by this existing (and only) filter. And the `context.Exception` contains the specified exception.